# Is there a database supporting 2 geospatial indexes?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I am looking for a database implementing 2 geospatial indexes or allowing to simulate it efficiently.

Motivation: our application deals with vectors, rather than locations and we often need to locate all the records where the source is near something and the destination is near something else.

Mongodb does not have it. Is there a database, which does?

May be it could be simulated with the mongodb map reduce feature, where the database looks up all the records satisfying the source constraint and then passes it through the map-reduce to leave those, which satisfy the destination constraint as well. Did anyone do it?

Thanks.

Comment: This can't be done-- the map/reduce function cannot take an array, which is inevitably required when pointing to geospatial coordinates.

Comment: The map-reduce key is the record id, not the coordinates. The problem is calculating the map function, where I have to check whether the second coordinate is within some region, I have no idea how to do it and I fear it will kill the performance.

Comment: Any explanations for downvoting?

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to fake this with MapReduce in Mongo, but this would only be suitable for use as a batch job and not likely to perform well as an application level query.

A workaround would be to store the source and destination points in separate Mongo collections. Then you could do a query on the source collection using $near to pull the closest points to the source point, then do another $near query against the destination  collection, and compute the intersection in memory.

Another option - since you can use the geospatial index to index a field which contains an array of points, store both the source and destination points as elements in an array. Then issue two queries to that collection (one for the source point, one for the destination) and scan through the two result sets to calculate the final result (the queries won't distinguish between which match was the source and which was the destination, so you'd have to check that on the client side).